# acer e14 e5-474g not detecting wireless on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, wireless, acer, atheros

I have just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a **Acer e14 e5-474g**.

On older hardware, when I go into software & updates, select the additional drivers tab, it detects the hardware drivers for wireless & it's as simple as clicking on the user proprietary driver radio button.

For **474g**, Ubuntu does not detect the wireless driver. I wonder if any one out there has this experience & has found a workaround? I'm not even sure what is the type of wireless adaptor.

```
alvinh@aspire474G:~$ sudo lshw -C net
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
       logical name: enp2s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: f0:76:1c:ce:2d:1a
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 ip=192.168.1.65 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:276 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94404000-94404fff memory:94400000-94403fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:94200000-943fffff
```

I did send the machine into the customer service center to get the memory upgraded. I hope the service person remembered to re-connect the wireless adaptor. By the look of the procedure on youtube, it's an easy thing to forget!

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. The output of `lshw -C net *-network` doesn't include the device PCI ID.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the machine with 16.04 general release. Did an update, still didn't work. About 2 weeks ago, ie abt the last week of july 2016, i did another update. Honestly, i don't know what happened, but the machine started to detect other wifi SSIDs around. I configured my SSID which is hidden & it worked; at least with 2.4G Wifi! I don't remember if the 5G wifi was ever working, but at least i have a working wifi which i'm quite happy about! Typically, Atheros wifis "Just work," not sure watt was in the updates, but thanks whoever put it there!